# C++: Calling an Overload of pure virtual method in base from derived instance

Tags: c++, inheritance, g++, overriding, overloading

I have a base class that comprises an abstract method `func(int, float, unsigned)` and an overload to this method `func(int)`, and a Derived class that implements the abstract method
.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void func(int x, float y, unsigned z) = 0;

    void func(int x)
    {
        cout << "func with x only" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void func(int x, float y, unsigned z)
    {
        cout << "func override" << endl;
    }

};
```

In my code, I have an instance of the derived class that calls the overloaded method of the base `func(int)`.

```
int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.func(10);     // <<--------- 'COMPILATION ERROR'
    return 0;
}
```

At compiling this piece of code, I get the following compilation error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Derived::func(int&)'
note: candidates are: virtual void Derived::func(int, float, unsigned int)
```

What 's the reason for this error / why this code does not work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bring the base class function into the derived class' *namespace*.

Do this by writing

```
using Base::func;
```

somewhere in the declaration of your child class.

Note that you are *overloading* `func`, not *overriding* it.

Comment: It worked thanks. I know I am 'overloading' func not overriding, I already wrote this in the question. However, I did not get the reason why it did not work without the `using` keyword like other methods in the base class

Comment: @user2758900 it's about name hiding.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Maybe. It's too early on a Monday to discuss semantics, so I'll remove my comment.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I think it supposed to be an overload in the Base-class scope

Answer (score 0):

In c++11 :

```
int main()
{
    Base && b = Derived();
    b.func(10);    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The issue here is calling `Base::func` from an object of `Derived` which means `b` should be of type `Derived`. When being of type `Derived`, the call fails at compilation as the `func` implmented in `Derived` hides the name `func` which exists in `Base`.